# Possible to include several pages in the == page_name check in PHP?

Tags: php, css

I'm writing a simple menu in PHP.

Its used to set `class="active"` in CSS.

However, I have a dropdown menu, consisting of 2 menu-items.
I would like this dropdown menu to get activated as long as pagename is either of the 2 menu items.

As you see I have found a solution using 2 separate PHP functions. However I would like to know how similar would work as just 1 PHP function :)

```
<li class=" <?php echo ($page_name=='personas.php')?'active':'';?> <?php echo ($page_name=='scenarier.php')?'active':'';?> dropdown">`
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php, http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `in_array()` (https://www.php.net/in_array)

```
<li class="<?php echo  in_array($page_name, array('personas.php', 'scenarier.php')) ?'active':'';?> dropdown">
```

Comment: (Although @Velox's answer is better, if it's just two elements)

Comment: Thanks. When would it be considered easier to use array over the or statement below?

Comment: The `||` should be quicker than `in_array()`. I would use `in_array()` if the number of page names to check may vary, or if you already have them represented in an array, or if the number of pages to check is large enough to make writing the sequence of `||` annoying.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is the OR operator.

```
if($page_name == 'personas.php' || $page_name == 'scenarier.php'){
    echo 'active';
}
```